# Nextflow does not create the number of expected output files

Tags: r, groovy, nextflow

I have the following example Nextflow pipeline, which I am using to A) preprocess a matrix and B) do some calculation with that matrix and a second matrix. I am doing the preprocessing with several replicates. In the case that I would create 5 replicates, I would expect to have 5 output files from process A, feed them into process B and then again get 5 result files from process B. However, I only get a single output file from process B and it seems like its a random replicate each time.
Here is the example command line output of the scripts below (note how process B only runs one single time and not 5 times as I would expect):

```
Launching `test.nf` [hungry_brenner] DSL2 - revision: 51e005477c
executor >  local (6)
[c4/ef0279] process > A (3) [100%] 5 of 5 ✔
[67/32ce50] process > B (1) [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[dataset_1, dataset_2, 4, method_X]
```

Can someone see what I am missing here?

nextflow script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

params.replicates = 5

process A {
    input: 
    tuple path(mat), val(ds)
    each replicate
    path preProcess_dir
    
    output:
    tuple path("${preProcess_dir}/${ds}_${replicate}_subset.rds"),
          val(ds),
          val(replicate)
    
    shell:
    '''
    scriptA.R '!{mat}' '!{ds}' '!{replicate}' '!{preProcess_dir}'
    '''
}


process B {
  input:
  tuple path(A_matrix), val(ds), val(replicate)
  tuple path(mat2), val(ds2) 
  each method
  path results_dir
  
  output:
  tuple val(ds),
        val(ds2),
        val(replicate),
        val(method)
  
  
  shell:
  '''
  scriptB.R '!{A_matrix}' '!{ds}' '!{mat2}' '!{ds2}' '!{replicate}' '!{method}' '!{results_dir}'
  '''
  
}


workflow{
  inputA = Channel.of(['/path/to/matrix_A.rds','dataset_1'])
  replicates = (1..params.replicates).toList()
  out_A = A(inputA, replicates, '/path/to/preprocess_results/')
  
  input_B = Channel.of(['/path/to/matrix_B.rds','dataset_2'])
  out_B = B(out_A, input_B, 'method_X', '/path/to/final_results/')
  
  out_B.view()
}
```

scriptA.R:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

library(docopt)

"Usage:
  scriptA.R <mat> <ds> <replicate> <outdir> 
Options:
<mat> path to  matrix
<ds> name of dataset
<replicate> value of replicate number
<outdir> output directory"  -> doc

args <- docopt::docopt(doc)

mat <- readRDS(args$mat)
subset_mat <- mat[sample(1:nrow(mat), 20),] # sample 20 random rows

out_path <- paste0(args$outdir,'/',args$ds, '_', args$replicate)
saveRDS(subset_mat, paste0(out_path,'_subset.rds'))
```

scriptB.R

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

library(docopt)

"Usage:
  scriptB.R <mat> <ds> <mat2> <ds2> <replicate> <method> <outdir> 
Options:
<mat> path to  matrix
<ds> name of dataset
<mat2> path to  matrix2
<ds2> name of dataset2
<replicate> value of replicate number
<method> function to be applied to matrix 1 and 2
<outdir> output directory"  -> doc

args <- docopt::docopt(doc)

mat <- readRDS(args$mat)
mat2 <- readRDS(args$mat2)

if(args$method == 'method_X'){
  res <- sum(mat) + sum(mat2)  # do something with the 2 matrices
}

out_path <- paste0(args$outdir,'/',args$method, '_', args$ds, '_', args$ds2, '_', args$replicate)
saveRDS(res, paste0(out_path,'_output.rds'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually occurs when a process erroneously receives two or more [queue](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#queue-channel) channels. Most of the time, what you want is one queue channel and one or more [value](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value-channel) channels when you require [multiple input channels](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#process-multiple-input-channels).

In this case, both `out_A` *and* `input_B` are queue channels. Note that `input_B` is a queue channel that emits a single list item. You can instead use the [`value`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value) factory method *or* simply pass in a list object. The latter works because a value channel is implicitly created by a process when it is invoked with a simple value<sup>[1](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#channel-type-value)</sup>.

Also, be sure to avoid absolute paths in your workflow script. For your workflow to be portable, processes should only access files in the working directory (i.e. `./work`). Perhaps someting like:

```
params.datasets_csv = './datasets.csv'
params.replicates = 5

params.outdir = './results'
```

```
process proc_A {

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/preprocessing", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    tuple val(ds), path(matrix)
    each replicate

    output:
    tuple val(replicate), val(ds), path("${ds}_${replicate}_subset.rds")

    script:
    """
    scriptA.R \\
        "${matrix}" \\
        "${ds}" \\
        "${replicate}" \\
        ./
    """
}
```

```
process proc_B {

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/final", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    tuple val(replicate), val(ds1), path(A_matrix), val(ds2), path(B_matrix)
    each method

    output:
    path "${method}_${ds1}_${ds2}_${replicate}_output.rds"

    script:
    """
    scriptB.R \\
        "${A_matrix}" \\
        "${ds1}" \\
        "${B_matrix}" \\
        "${ds2}" \\
        "${replicate}" \\
        "${method}" \\
        ./
    """
}
```

```
workflow {

    replicates = (1..params.replicates).toList()
    methods = [ 'method_X', 'method_Y', 'method_Z' ]

    Channel
        .fromPath( params.datasets_csv )
        .splitCsv( header: true )
        .branch { row ->
            def (id, num) = row.dataset.split('\\.', 2)

            input_A: id == "dataset_1"
                return tuple( row.dataset, file(row.matrix) )
            input_B: id == "dataset_2"
                return tuple( row.dataset, file(row.matrix) )
        }
        .set { datasets }

    out_A = proc_A( datasets.input_A, replicates )
    out_B = proc_B( out_A.combine(datasets.input_B), methods )
```

Example contents of *datasets.csv*:

```
dataset,matrix
dataset_1.1,/path/to/matrix_A1.rds
dataset_1.2,/path/to/matrix_A2.rds
dataset_2.1,/path/to/matrix_B1.rds
dataset_2.2,/path/to/matrix_B2.rds
dataset_2.3,/path/to/matrix_B3.rds
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run main.nf 
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.04.0
Launching `main.nf` [drunk_venter] DSL2 - revision: e7d33025b0
executor >  local (100)
[ed/f85b29] process > proc_A (10) [100%] 10 of 10 ✔
[10/645eb4] process > proc_B (90) [100%] 90 of 90 ✔
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess I did not read the documentation good enough ;)

Comment: Also, yes you make a good point about the static file paths. I was only showing them here like this example.

Comment: I have a new question: How would I need to change the script, if input_A and input_B can contain more than one tuple? So for example: ` input_A = [[ matrix_A1, 'dataset_1.1' ], [ matrix_A2, 'dataset_1.2' ]] `

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure how you intend to create or populate the array. I think instead `input_A` should probably be a (queue) channel like what you had originally. You could then use the [combine](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#combine) operator to create the cartesian product as input into _proc_B_. In my example above I just parse a simple CSV file to conveniently create the `input_A` and `input_B` channels.